# scale image down, width 100% and fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have high resolution images (2592x1944) and I'm having problem to show them in a slider.

I'm using a fixed container (width 100% and height 550px) and inside it the image as background (maybe I should use img tag?).

```
<div class="header-right">
    <div class="banner">
         <div class="slider">
            <div class="callbacks_container">
                <ul class="rslides" id="slider">
                    <li>
                        <div class="banner">
                            <div class="caption">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS (the background url is in the html so i can dynamically add more slides with php):

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
}
.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.rslides li {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.rslides li:first-child {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
}
.banner{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
}
```

Currently it's displaying the full image scaled (height 550px) aligned to left.

I'd like to show the image with a full width and the borders cropped (in a way that the image can fit in the 100% of the screen and have a good amount of the height and can be properly displyed). The images are camera photos (smartphone) and they have too much height to be in a 16:9 format so maybe cropping it it'll help. I think it's better to use css rather than modify the images one by one.

How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/5n9mo3od/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to use cover instead of contain for this? Cropping is in fact a good solution because not the whole image would be loaded. An image of 2500+ width can be hard to load on a smartphone.

Comment: Yes I did but it shows from the upper left the entire image, so it'll only show a small portion. I think I'll better manually crop the images, since not all the images will have the same "optional space" that can be removed.

Comment: And when you use background-position: center center; ?

Comment: That works, well it shows the center of the image but anyways the image is too big and needs to be scaled down and remove the unnecessary space. Thanks, I'll use cover and position center center.